# Validity of camera calibration after changing focus

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration, picamera

I have a camera and I am focusing it at 10 cm distance at the time of calibration using checkerboard and open cv. Some time after calibration I am changing the focus to 100 cm and taking some photos and then again I am focusing at 10 cm, but this time I am using calibration results we generated in starting. Are those calibration results invalid because I have changed the focus in between? Or is it valid, as I am focusing at the same distance where I have calibrated the camera?

The reason to ask this question is, at long distance/far objects focus do not changes to much but my application of camera lies to work between 100 cm to 10 cm where I need to change focus continuously. Are there any options are available for it?

**My Idea:**
Calibrate camera at 2 different mainly important distances (40 cm and 10 cm), and use different set of calibration parameters at both the distances where accuracy is required.
Will it work?

I have tried calibrating the camera in auto focus mode but people are talking that it's invalid as calibration parameters changes drastically at different focus points and can not be combined using different images with different focus distance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is a conceptual discussion, so code is not needed @Community

Comment: What is enough for your actual work depends on the your work.
So, I think, what you should do is actually measuring/evaluating how focus-changing affect to the your work.

Comment: I guess, thinking very very simple, ideally, what changes when focus changes is only 2 parameters `{fx,fy}`.
If so (if it can be assumed so on your situation), you will be able to construct function `{fx,fy} = SomeFunc(focus)` from measurement(calibration) results at several focuses, and you can estimate `{fx,fy}` values for any focuses with this function.

Comment: On the forum some people are saying that changing the focal length invalids whole calibration... so is it also affect other parameters too? or just fx and fy as you have mentiond ?

Comment: Whan assuming ideal(no distortion) camera, i.e. camera model is pinhole-camera-model, intrinsic parameters are only {cx,cy,fx,fy}.
On this situation, if focus changing do not affect to {cx,cy}, who will be affected are {fx,fy}.
Of course, you will use other more complex camera model (dealing with distortions) actually, and the camera model will have more intrinsic parameters, and they may be affected by focus changing.
But to what extent? Are distortions really changes drastically?
What I said is you should evaluate the extent to make your decision.

Comment: If you **found** that "the changes is existing but some of them are very few and so can be ignored them for the your actual work", you can do so.
Or, if you **found** some correlation between parameter value and focal length, you may be able to model it.